# Blissey Base Daylight saving time

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm looking for way to grind some Pokemon to build a living National Dex. I found out about the Blissey Base method of powerleveling, and went through the steps to do it. I realized that I still had not fixed the time from DST, and had to move the clock forward an hour (since some timer resets at midnight, it was midnight locally, but 23:00 in-game).

So I changed the time hoping to be able to get access to the base. Nope. From what I've read, when you save the game, it also sets the system time somewhere, and if there is a discrepancy, or if you go back and forth between systems, the game resets the clocks, and you have to wait until midnight the next-next day.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to undo the setting of the system clock so that I can access the bases at tomorrow's midnight?
2. What happens during Daylight saving time? We have to manually adjust the times anyways, so do we lose 4 days per year of Secret Base stuff? Or should we just not touch the time at all?

Comment: Yes, you have to manually adjust the clock and you'll lose 4 days per year for every time-based event for each game you play.

Comment: I believe the answer to 1 is no and 2 is yes, but I don't have a source so I'm not going to post a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you cannot 'undo' changing the clock. Even changing it back to the time it was before will still count as being 'changed'.
2. If you adjust for daylight's saving time, then yes. However, nothing that I know of relies on having an accurate time set on your DS, so you're pretty safe to never change the DS clock if you don't need to.